# what is apache hbase rest api ip and port?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have HBase installed on another computer, and I can access to management page using this IP address and port:

[My HBase Web Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNzix.png)

But when I try to use REST API URL's such as /version I can't get info and I get a `404 Page Not Found` error. I don't know if this the right IP and port or for RST API or should I use another?

[404 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rJYo.png)